# Eclipse GEF/Draw2d: Bounds vs. Constraints

Tags: eclipse-gef, draw2d

Can someone explain the difference/relationship between bounds and constraints in Draw2d?

I'm trying to set up a GEF editor where instances of the same `EditPart` class are nested inside each other (I can post a simplified version of the code if necessary, but my question is really just conceptual).  Each figure has an `XYLayout` and I'm setting the bounds and constraints (`Rectangle`s) of each figure in `refreshVisuals`.

Right now my bounds and constraints are the same for each figure.  Is that correct?  Since I'm using `XYLayout`, are the coordinates of the bounds relative to the parent `Figure`?  How about for the constraints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bounds of a child figure are only relative to the parent figure, if `isCoordinateSystem()` of the parent returns `true` - which is hardly ever the case. So in practice bounds are absolute coordinates.

The rectangles you provide as constraints in `XYLayout` are expected to contain coordinates **relative to the parent** and the layout then converts those relative coordinates in a way that is appropriate. If e.g. no figure in the parent chain has a local coordinate system, then the resulting bounds will be absolute coordinates.

Comment: So in `refreshVisuals` should I only set the constraints and let `XYLayout` manage the bounds?  In the few examples I've seen, the constraints are set but not the bounds.

Comment: The point of a layout manager is to let it manage the bounds of its children according to the settings and constraints you provide. So the answer to your question is: yes.